# Unable to buy Pages of Blacksmithing from the Auction House

Tags: diablo-iii

### Note: The auction house no longer exists. This question is irrelevant to the current release of the game

---

When I go to the auction house, select pages and recipes -> artisan crafting -> pages of blacksmithing (or any of the pages), and i try to click buyout it wont let me.  it says you must purchase at least (coins worth)100 of this item.

Why can't i buy any recipes?  I haven't really used the auction house much but is it that there isn't enough stock of this item so i can't buy it out?

Comment: Question should be close as there is no longer an auction house for diablo 3.

Comment: @z- Question should not be closed. See [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8451/50582) to your own meta question about D3.

Comment: @BillyMailman the difference between the example and this one in D3 is the fact that you can't go back to a previous version of D3 where an AH exists, but in Minecraft you can play previous versions.

Comment: This discussion should be continued in the comment thread on the meta answer. But in the meantime, I will add the suggested disclaimer to my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer (because I am an idiot and didn't notice) is that you have to change the quantity before you press search.  This way you can have enough of the item to make it above the minimum price

Comment: gotta wait two more days? odd